# How would I read this sum. Convolution sum appearing in Forurier Galerkin methods.

Tags: summation

I'm wondering how to read this sum:

$$w_k = \sum_{p+q=k} u_p v_q$$

Comment: The sum of $u_p, v_q$ over the pairs of $(p, q)$ such that $p + q = k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You let $(p,q)$ run over all pairs (of integers? of naturals? depends on your settings) with the property $p+q=k$, compute $u_pv_q$ accordingly and add the results. A more wordy notation would thus be something like 
$$ \sum_{(p,q)\in \{\,(x,y)\in\Bbb N^2\mid x+y=k\,\}} u_pq_v,$$
which looks awful.
You may also rewrite it as 
$$w_k=\sum_pu_pv_{k-p} $$
(where you may additionally insert suitable lower and upper bounds for $p$), but that notation breaks the beautiful symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{p+q = k}u_pv_q$ means the same as 
$$\sum_{p = 0}^ku_pv_{k-p}$$(assuming your indices start at $0$).